# Debugging C# - stack overflow exception?

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

Below is my code for a Battleship game. I keep getting the following error:

> Process terminated due to StackOverflowException. .

It keeps pointing to

```
char[,] Grid = new char[10, 10];
```

How can this be fixed?

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BattleShip_Jamshid_Berdimuratov
{
class BattleshipBoard
{
    Player p = new Player();
    public void Randomize()
    {
        p.SetGrid(1, 2);
        p.SetGrid(2, 2);
        p.SetGrid(3, 2);
    }

    public void DisplayBoard(char[,] Board)
    {
        int Row;
        int Column;

        Console.WriteLine(" ¦ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9");
        Console.WriteLine("--+--------------------");
        for (Row = 0; Row <= 9; Row++)
        {
            Console.Write((Row).ToString() + " ¦ ");
            for (Column = 0; Column <= 9; Column++)
            {
                Console.Write(Board[Column, Row] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
}

class Player
{
    char[,] Grid = new char[10, 10];
    public int HitCount = 0;
    public int MissCount = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    BattleshipBoard b = new BattleshipBoard();

    public int getHitCount()
    {
        return HitCount;
    }
    public int getMissCount()
    {
        return MissCount;
    }
    public void AskCoordinates()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter X");
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        int value;
        if (int.TryParse(line, out value))
        {
            x = value;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not an integer!");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Y");
        line = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(line, out value))
        {
            y = value;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not an integer!");
        }

        try
        {
            if (Grid[x, y].Equals('S'))
            {
                Grid[x, y] = 'H';
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Hit!");
                HitCount += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Grid[x, y] = 'M';
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Miss!");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Please enter numbers between 0 and 9. (Inclusive)");
        }
    }
    public char[,] GetGrid()
    {
        return Grid;
    }
    public void SetGrid(int x, int y)
    {
        Grid[x, y] = 'S';
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "BerdShip!";
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Berdship!\r\n\r\n");
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        string name = System.Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        BattleshipBoard b = new BattleshipBoard();
        Player p = new Player();
        b.Randomize();
        while (p.getHitCount() < 12)
        {
            b.DisplayBoard(p.GetGrid());
            p.AskCoordinates();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, " + name + "! You Win!");
        Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing BerdShip. Press enter to quit.");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: +1 for StackOverflowException

Comment: first question: why does the Player class have a copy of the board? (and fixed size as well). Create a separate Board class...

Comment: WOW thanks Mitch lol fixed it

Comment: GetXYZ() and SetXYZ() methods should be removed and properties should be used instead. Please use proper local variables and private fields naming casing (ie., "Row" should be "row"). Have a look at JetBrain's Resharper while you're still new at coding. It should help you a lot with naming conventions (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Answer (score 10):

Your BattleshipBoard object creatse a Player object during construction, and your Player object creates a BattleshipBoard during construction. This iterates back and forth until you overflow the stack.

The call to:

```
BattleshipBoard b = new BattleshipBoard();
```

will never return and cause the overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Stack overflow is normally caused by infinite recusion; i.e. function A calls B and then B and A and A has no termination condition.

In your case, its the initialises of your two classes `BattleshipBoard` and `Player`.

Your `Player` creates a new `BattleshipBoard` and the `BattleshipBoard` creates a new `Player`!

Remove the line `Player p = new Player();` from the `BattleshipBoard` and all should be good.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to create your initial BattleshipBoard, it results in a infinite loop alternately creating your two types.

If you want the two classes to have a reference to the other corresponding class, then you can have your Player class take the BattleshipBoard in its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your `BattleShipBoard` has a `Player` which has a `BattleShipBoard` which has a `Player` which has a `BattleShipBoard` which has a [*...go on forever...*]

Hence, you have a stack overflow.